# Java Switch statement throwing Java.lang.NullPointerException - Android Beginner

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I am a new beginner so please bear with me. I created a spinner and populated it with a string array, I then created a the method "OnItemSelected" and inserted a switch statement. The activity then throws a NullPointerException. When I remove the switch statement, the activity works. How can i fix this?

Code:

```
EditText player1 = null;
EditText player2 = null;
EditText player3 = null;
EditText player4 = null;
EditText player5 = null;
EditText player6 = null;
EditText player7 = null;
EditText player8 = null;

Spinner spinner;

int numberOfPlayers = 0;
int counter = 0;

private String[] players ={"2","3","4", "5", "6", "7", "8"};
//private String[] names ={" "};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {        
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerplayers);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, players);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }catch (Exception e) {

        // handle any errors

        Log.e("TestActivity", "Error in activity", e);  // log the error

        // Also let the user know something went wrong

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
        long id) {
        numberOfPlayers = pos + 2;

    /*switch(pos){
    case 0:
        player1.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer1);
        player2.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer2);

        player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 1:
        player1.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer1);
        player2.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer2);
        player3.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer3);

        player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 2:
        player1.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer1);
        player2.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer2);
        player3.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer3);
        player4.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer4);

        player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 3: 
        player1.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer1);
        player2.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer2);
        player3.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer3);
        player4.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer4);
        player5.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer5);

        player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 4:
        player1.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer1);
        player2.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer2);
        player3.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer3);
        player4.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer4);
        player5.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer5);
        player6.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer6);

        player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 5:
        player1.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer1);
        player2.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer2);
        player3.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer3);
        player4.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer4);
        player5.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer5);
        player6.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer6);
        player7.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer7);

        player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 6:
        player1.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer1);
        player2.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer2);
        player3.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer3);
        player4.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer4);
        player5.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer5);
        player6.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer6);
        player7.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer7);
        player8.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer8);

        player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    }*/

}
```

and then here is my logcat:

```
    06-06 12:44:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5764): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 12:44:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5764): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 12:44:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5764):     at com.brightdesign.truthordare.Main.onItemSelected(Main.java:69)
06-06 12:44:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5764):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:873)
06-06 12:44:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5764):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:45)
06-06 12:44:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5764):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:839)
06-06 12:44:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5764):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-06 12:44:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5764):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-06 12:44:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5764):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-06 12:44:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5764):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-06 12:44:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5764):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 12:44:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5764):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-06 12:44:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5764):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-06 12:44:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5764):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-06 12:44:42.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5764):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What line is it? I don't even see an un-commented switch statement. What's null? How can we help?

Comment: apart from the actual issue, you can avoid a lot of repetition by counting downward in the switch, and omitting the breaks to let execution go through the cases following it.      i.e. case 6: player8.xxx; case 5: player7.xxx; case 4:player6.xxx; etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this causes the problems in your code within the onItemSelected()-method:

```
player1.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer1);
player2.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer2);
//...
```

The method findViewById() returns a sub view of another view or of the main view of the activity. In your case the references seem to be Null pointers and you also do not handle the result, which would be the only reason to use the method.

You should set these references only once in your onCreate()-method:

```
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerplayers);
//...
player1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer1);
player2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer2);
//...
```

This way all your references are valid after onCreate() and you can access them securely in the onItemSelected() method (which I assume caused the NullPointerException)

Comment: Thanks... I cant believe I made such a stupid mistake. I guess when you just get used to the code, you don't realize when you do something basic wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You setup the global variable and then used the local variable so, the variable is still null.

That's the only problem I could deduce from your code as half of the onItemSelected is commented out.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a null pointer at com.brightdesign.truthordare.Main.onItemSelected(Main.java:69). The exception is the answer, not the question :-)

Given that you have the line "EditText player1 = null;" and we never see it assigned, we'd have to be psychic to help you (unless this really is all the code, in which case you need to go back to your "Learn Java" books and cover the basics).

You need to assign it before you access it. It is null.

Answer (score 0):

findViewById should be called on the parent of the view you are looking for.

Instead of

```
player1.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer1);
```

you need

```
player1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use the `switch`'s fall-through capabilities to your advantage:

```
switch(pos){
case 2:
    player4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer4);
    player4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // Notice: no break command!

case 1:
    player3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer3);
    player3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

case 0: default:
    player1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer1);
    player2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer2);

    player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

This code tries to find each EditText in main.xml and sets that View to your appropriate `player` variables.